# clone an existing project in gitLab

Tags: java, repository, gitlab

First, I was working on a spring project in STS, I created a project in GitLab and commit it to GitLab. Now, I messed up, I deleted the project that existed locally.
How can I clone the project existing in GitLab and create a new repository?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is just typing the following command. You should have Git CLI installed.

```
git clone "link here"
```

for example,

```
git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2
```

When you go to the project dashboard in GitLab, you will see the project URL. When you enter he above command, it will ask for the username of your GitLab account and the password. Once you enter them, repo will be cloned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact I did, but when I change something in the project and I try to push it I have the following error : 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: check **git remote origin** and see it's the correct url. If not, use **git remote remove origin** and **git remote add origin <new remote url>**

Comment: I did, but, here's a new error that occurs : 
Sony@SONY-VAIO ~/Documents/PFE_ (master)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: seems like the remote origin url is not correct, or may be a problem with the internet connection